Стоит ли предлагать предложенные в поиске проверки дубликаты для простых вопросов с нечеткой формулировкой?
Если у ТС есть простой вопрос, он не отвечает на комментарии, не исправляет вопрос, на который, кажется, наверняка должен быть дубликат в системе, стоит ли предлагать ему похожий дубликат, чтобы у него был выбор? Возможно, это поможет ему найти ответ или хотя бы навести его на мысль, как правильно сформулировать вопрос.
Пример: есть вопрос, я предложила дубликат, который система посчитала похожим (всем нам известно, что автоматический поиск дубликатов не всегда находит точные совпадения, но иногда предлагает вопросы с похожей тематикой). В данном случае в вопросе было мало деталей, и формулировка была не совсем ясной. Чтобы помочь автору, я предложила "похожий" вопрос, надеясь, что это побудит его обратить внимание и, возможно, изменить свой вопрос.
Позже в обсуждении появился опытный участник по Python и отметил, что предложенный мной дубликат не подходит. Пользуясь его присутствием, я предложила другие возможные дубликаты — 2, 3 и 4 — рассчитывая, что он может помочь выбрать наиболее подходящий вариант. Однако опытный участник ответил:

«не нужно искать дубликат, пока детали вопроса не ясны».

Идея в том, что сам вопрос действительно был краткий, (это была очеред проверок) и я смотрела есть ли в системе подходящие дубликаты. Поиск предложил вопрос с упоминанием .exe файла для Python, и я сочла это подходящим вариантом. Когда другой участник указал, что дубликат не подходит, я решила, что он сможет помочь выбрать более точный вариант. Но вместо этого он порекомендовал вовсе не искать дубликат, пока вопрос не станет яснее.
В таких ситуациях, когда вопрос кажется простым, но нечетко сформулированным, и кажется, что дубликат наверняка должен быть, стоит ли все-таки предлагать похожие вопросы, чтобы направить ТС? Или действительно лучше воздержаться от поиска дубликатов, пока автор не уточнит ВСЕ детали?
Прошу рассмотреть именно эту ситуацию, а не случаи, когда вопрос полностью неясен и ТС активно реагирует на комментарии и пытается исправить свой вопрос.
//p.s.формулировка не ясный вопрос/мало деталей/итд, ок, но когда что то очевидное, может все-таки поискать дубликат?так и ТС может даже ответ найти...

Если формулировка нечеткая - однозначно не нужно закрывать дубликатом на рандомный похожий вопрос. Вы так фактически даете на вопрос потенциально неверный ответ. Нужно просто закрыть вопрос до уточнения формулировки (что и произошло).

Когда вопрос неясен, план действий максимально простой - голосовать за закрытие с вариантом "вопрос не понятен". Не понятно, с чего вдруг непонятные вопросы нужно закрывать как дубликаты.

"стоит ли все-таки предлагать похожие вопросы, чтобы направить ТС" - это стоит делать через комментарии, а не через закрытие дубликатом

@insolor, так нечестно, вы сами отвечаете на ваше же мнение//да, ок неясен-закрыли(обычно так и делаю), но иногда как будто хочешь показать. а вот есть это...это не оно? особенно, когда видишь, что вопрос сложно сформулирован-то есть это не сильная сторона ТС.

Еще раз: закрытие дубликатом нужно для однозначных дубликатов. Для неоднозначных непонятных случаев есть свой вариант закрытия.

@insolor, это стоит делать через комментарии, а не через закрытие дубликатом => а что делать в проверках? вопрос же явно для закрытия //рука не поднилась в этом случае просто закрыть по типу непонятна суть вопроса, и поэтому захотелось дать дубликатов

В проверках - переходите по ссылке на вопрос, пишете комментарий, возвращаетесь на вкладку проверки, выбираете "другое действие" (как-то так обычно работает)

В любом случае, если вы не полностью понимаете вопрос, не нужно его закрывать (никаким способом). Нужно пройти мимо (или попытаться с помощью комментариев выяснить все детали)

@avp, по вопросу видно, что его закроют 200 процентов. Там три человека не поняли. И если пройти мимо, то ТС не получит вообще никакого ответа, и вопрос высохнет в углу в глубоком одиночестве... Я ставлю в закладки вопросы, которым уделили мало внимания, и потом правлю их, чтоб они поднялись в топик, но если вопрос не ясен, то простая правка (взять код в кавычки итд) не поможет. Надо, чтоб ТС отреагировал и изменил как то, либо откликнулся. Если просто пройти... Все в тишине, по моему это мало поможет

Часто я делаю как insolor говорит, даю ссылку в комментариях, но видимо сегодня это была лень (?) //я считаю неудобно это, открыть... Искать... Вставить... //уже окно проверки открыто, можно добавить "не закрыть вопрос дубликатом"... А "предложить похожие вопросы"... Если тс сам не поискал, мы как справку даём, так же можно похожее предложить, но, чтоб было прям в проверках.... Было бы супер круто и удобно

А формулировка... Что то типа"выберите из дубликатов, либо ваш вопрос закроют так как не ясна суть вопроса..."

@Dev18, вот в результате всех подобных действий сайтик и усыхает... (с обоих концов, между прочим)

@avp, Не-а, это тут не при чем

Закрыть беспочвенно одно, а закрыто, что не ясно другое...//ябыс удовольствием пообщалась на эту тему, но вопрос не в том же в данной теме)))//если будет много комментариев их прячут, и я больше не смогу отслеживать стрелочки (кол-во) вверх на высказывании- на втором комментарии:/
